# pull from one git branch, push into another

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket-server

I have a local BitBucket server, and I merge my changes into master from the web UI.
I'd like to work with a permanent personal branch, that I will periodically create merge requests from.

I'd like `git pull` to merge `origin/master` into my local `master`, and `git push` to push my local master into `origin/itsadok`. I will then create a merge request on the server, and merge my changes from `origin/itsadok` into `origin/master`.

```
BitBucket server:   origin/itsadok --- via PR --> origin/master
                       ↑                              |
Local machine:          \---------- master <---------/
```

Seems simple enough.

I know I can manually do `git push origin master:itsadok`, but I'd like it do be the default. It seems that the only way to set the default push target is to config `branch.master.merge` to `refs/heads/itsadok` (and config `push.default` to `upstream`), but then pull will merge from my personal branch as well.

Is there a way to configure git so that the default push and pull will work as described above?

**Edit**: It occurred to me that I can achieve something very similar by setting `push.default` to `current`, naming the local branch the same as the remote personal branch, and setting `branch.itsadok.merge` to refs/heads/master. In other words:

```
BitBucket server:   origin/itsadok --- via PR --> origin/master
                       ↑                              |
Local machine:          \---------- itsadok <--------/
```

This almost works, but because I have scripts that assume my local branch is called `master`, this solution is rather inconvenient for me. If there are no other idea, though, I'll settle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve described behavior by proper mapping of push refspecs. As described in [push manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), git looks on what to push in the following order:

- explicitly listed arguments or options in command line if exist
- `remote.<remote_name>.push` configuration if not empty
- `push.default` configuration otherwise

So you can make `master` tracking `origin\master`, so pulling works fine, and then configure `remote.origin.push`, so push without arguments fits your workflow:

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/itsadok
```

You can check your configuration by printing upstream branch with `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}` and push branch with `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{push}`

However, there are couple of caveats:

- `git status` will compare master with its upstream, so you will see "1 commit ahead" notification even after commit is actually pushed.
- invoking `git push` without arguments, while on non-master branch will still push data from master to itsadok. If you want to try fixing this, probably the best way to start is [refspec configuration examples](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)